# GetX Controller in Stack (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Im using GetX Controller in Screen A and navigating to the Screen B which is also a same screen with different data's but same Controller, (its a concept of navigating inside and inside the users profile in social media app - reference: Instagram)

The issue is when i navigates from Screen A to Screen B, Screen B data is fetched from the API which is totally fine, then when we clicks back button it return back to Screen A, but the Screen A data is replaced with Screen B data

Initialized controller like

```
 final ProfileViewController userProfileController =
      Get.put(ProfileViewController());
```

Navigating to screen like

```
Get.to(() => ScreenB());
```

Expecting the best solution, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

I did this and it worked fine, hope it helps

in main.dart

```
Get.create(() => ProfileViewController());
```

then in the view

```
ProfileViewController_con = Get.find();

Get.to(() => const ScreenB(), preventDuplicates: false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After 2 times screens not opening any more in my case. preventDuplicates: false saved me

Answer (score 1):

Try to find and use GetWidget in GetX

With GetWidget, you will have a separate new controller for each widget instance.

```
class ProfileViewWidget extends GetWidget< ProfileViewController > {...}
...

class YourAnyScreenBindings implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put(YourAnyScreenCtrl());
    Get.create(() => ProfileViewController());
  }
}
...

List<GetPage<dynamic>> getPages = [
  GetPage(
    name: '/your_any_screen',
    page: () => YourAnyScreen(),
    binding: YourAnyScreenBindings(),
  ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tag` with the controller

Initialize controller like

```
final ProfileViewController userProfileController =
  Get.put(ProfileViewController(),tag:'a_string_may_be_the_profile_id');
```

usage:

```
var controller = Get.find<ProfileViewController>(tag:'a_string_may_be_the_profile_id')
```

By this way, more than one profile controller can be created and accessed